# How can I invoke a WSO2 data service from html/javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have created a GET WSO2 DSS Data service. This does not take any input parameters. the data service does a 'select * from table'.

i want to view this data on a html data table.
i am not coding in c# this is pure html so I would have to use javascript/jquery.

does anyone have some way of populating table rows for the requirement above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way I invoke my DSS from my html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DSS Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>    
        <div>Consume DSS</div>
    <table border='1' id="pharmacy">   
    <tr>
        <td><b>Id</b></td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Latitude</b></td>
        <td><b>Longitude</b></td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://169.254.193.10:9763/services/testGet/getAllJson",              
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (jsonObject) {      
                    $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
                        $.each(obj, function (i1, obj1) {                         
                            $.each(obj1, function (i2, obj2) {
                            var id = obj2.ID;
                            var name = obj2.Descripcion;
                            var Latitude = obj2.Latitude;
                            var Longitude = obj2.Longitude;
                            $('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + 
                            name + '</td><td>' + Latitude + '</td><td>' +
                                         Longitude + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#pharmacy');              
                            });                                  
                        });                                  
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the respomse of my dss

```
{
  "Pharmacies": {
    "Pharmacy": [
      {
        "Image": "foto.jpg",
        "ID": "5",
        "Latitude": "1",
        "Longitude": "2",
        "Descripcion": "Pharmacy NATURAL"
      },
      {
        "Image": "foto.jpg",
        "ID": "6",
        "Latitude": "2",
        "Longitude": "2",
        "Descripcion": "Pharmacy TRADICIONAL"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you get past the "Cross-origin resource sharing" CORS error returned from the webpage. I had this and eventualy had to wrap my data service in a managed API to enable the CORS settings. this leaves me with another issue...oAuth Dynamic key allocation. which i have not yet solved

Comment: Enabling CORS for Data Services in DSS https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Enabling+CORS+for+Data+Services

Comment: Thank you for that. Would this be safe against hackers to expose the data service directly?